# How to run express function synchronously

Tags: node.js, express

how to get out put on the following express code?

```
res_X;
res_Y;
function A(){
  method_X(function(data){
     res_X=data;
  console.log("x_res: "res_X);
  });
  method_Y(function(data){
     res_Y=data;
     console.log("Y_res: "res_Y);
  });
  if(res_X.msg!='failed' && res_Y.msg!='failed'){
     method_Z(res_X,res_Y,function(res_Z){
        return  {res_X,res_Y,res_Z};
       });
  }else return return  {res_X,res_Y};;

 console output: 
    Y_res: msg:"passed"
    X_res: msg:"failed"
  return value is: {undefined,msg:"passed",msg:"finished"}
```

i want to get return value is {msg:"failed",msg:"passed"}. how to stop asynchronous execution in express js.

Answer (score 0):

try this, You can handle async call using promises or callback.

```
res_X;
res_Y;

function A(cb) {
  method_X(function (data) {
    res_X = data;
    method_Y(function (data) {
      res_Y = data;
      if (res_X.msg != 'failed' && res_Y.msg != 'failed') {
        method_Z(res_X, res_Y, function (res_Z) {
          return cb({
            res_X,
            res_Y,
            res_Z
          });
        });
      } else return cb({
        res_X,
        res_Y
      });
    });
  });
}


A((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```